# geo fix not working on Android app built with Xamarin mobile

Tags: android, geolocation, xamarin.android

I have an Android app that I am building with Xamarin mobile (MonoDroid). The app needs to get the gps coordinates of the current user. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to get the `PositionChanged` event to fire.

```
private Geolocator geolocator = null;
private void InitializeStuff()
{
  geolocator = new Geolocator(this) { DesiredAccuracy = 1 };          
  if (geolocator.IsGeolocationEnabled == false)
    statusTextView.Text = "Please allow this application to access your location.";                 
  else if (geolocator.IsGeolocationAvailable == false)
    statusTextView.Text = "Your location could not be determined.";     
  else
    statusTextView.Text = "Ready.";

  geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;

  myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
}

private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  statusTextView.Text = "Getting position...";
  if ((geolocator != null) && (geolocator.IsListening == true))
    geolocator.StartListening(minTime: 1000, minDistance: 0);
}

private void geolocator_PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
{
  RunOnUiThread(() =>
  {
    statusTextView.Text = "Lat: " + e.Position.Latitude.ToString("N6") + ", Long: " + e.Position.Longitude.ToString("N6");
  });
}
```

I can successfully get my app to the point where it is saying "Getting position...". However, the `PositionChanged` event never fires. I'm testing my app in an Android emulator as I do not have an Android device. I am testing this feature by tenet-ing into the emulator. Then, I enter the following command:

```
geo fix -73.985708 40
```

The command window says "OK". However, the `PositionChanged` event never fires. My emulator is an Android 2.2 emulator. Thank you for any insights you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your condition in your if-statement to be wrong in the `myButton_Click` handler:

```
if ((geolocator != null) && (geolocator.IsListening == true))
```

The above means that if the geolocator is not null and it IS listening, then you start listenening for position changes. If you change that to be:

```
if ((geolocator != null) && (geolocator.IsListening != true))
```

it should work as expected.

**EDIT:**
Also you don't really need those parenthesis around your two conditions and it could be written:

```
if (geolocator != null && geolocator.IsListening == true)
```

Comment: grrr... sometimes its the little things that will drive you nuts. I can't believe I kept overlooking that if-statement. thank you for your help.

Comment: Happens to us all. A good way to catch this is to use the debugger and step through your application.